# Mysql query with group by and having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I am constructing query to get the maximum price for same product.
I have table as

```
-----------------------------------------
|   prod_id  |   price   |    user_id   |
-----------------------------------------
|     4      |   25      |       1      |
|     4      |   38      |       2      |
|     4      |   41      |       3      |
|     7      |   100     |       1      |
|     7      |   95      |       2      |
-----------------------------------------
```

I am trying to get following output:

```
-----------------------------------------
|     4      |   41      |       3      |
-----------------------------------------
|     7      |   100     |       1      |
-----------------------------------------
```

I have constructed following query which is not right.

```
select * from user_bid group by prod_id having max(price);
```

Can someone guide me to get the query for desired results.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved, you've already got answers that fit only one those.

Comment: @jarih: it is possible for more than one db engine to be used in a project. (though in this case probably not since the question mentions only mysql)

Comment: @Kris, I know that, but it's rare. Since more than 99% of the posts having multiple dbms tags do that incorrectly I use to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM user_bid 
WHERE (prodid, price) IN
(
    SELECT prodid, MAX(price)
    FROM user_bid 
    GROUP BY prod_id
)
```

Comment: Does MySQL support row and table constructors?

Comment: Interesting...I had no idea this was possible in MySQL.

Comment: How is this performance-wise, compared to @TimBiegeleisen's JOIN version?

Comment: @jarih since mine is a more simpler query, i guess it would be better performance wise

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using a join:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM prod_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT prod_id, MAX(price) AS price    -- this inner subquery finds the maximum
    FROM user_bid                          -- price for each product group
    GROUP BY prod_id
) p2
    ON p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id AND         -- and this join condition retains
       p1.price   = p2.price               -- only records which have this maximum
                                           -- price for each product group
```

And here is an option which uses a subquery:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM prod_id p1
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(p2.price) FROM prod_id p2 WHERE p1.prod_id = p2.prod_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server

```
;WITH cte AS

(
SELECT prod_id,price,user_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prod_id ORDER BY price desc) as rank
FROM table Name
)

SELECT prod_id,price,user_id
FROM cte
WHERE rank=1
```

Comment: Too bad OP is using MySQL... Not very fair.

Comment: he had tagged sql server .. now removed

Comment: I know, that's why I said it was unfair.

Comment: actually i have two DB with same schema mysql and sql server. I am believing the same query would work on both. That's the reason I have put 2 tags

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM user_bid  ORDER BY price DESC) AS Temp 
GROUP BY prod_id
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you create the tables and insert data as specified, and then try your query.

Comment: Yes, I did this and its working fine. I will add the output.

Comment: Don't know about other databases, i have tried with MySQL.

Comment: This may not even run the same on all versions of MySQL, so it might be better to not use it.